# left align div issues on different monitors

Tags: jquery, css

I've been going in circles with some CSS and need some help. I am trying to have a div slide down from a table cell on mouseover, but can't seem to get the div to left align with the table cell on all different monitors. On some monitors it works and some its not aligned(see below). I want it to look like the SE inbox in terms of alignment:

[image: Inbox]

Here is my code:
**HTML**:

```
<td class="inboxCell">
    <a data-badge="1" id="idInbox" class="inbox" src="http://www.someurl.com"/>
</td>
```

**Jquery**

```
var ele = $('#inboxCell');
$('.inboxMenu').show().slideDown(1000).css({
  display: "block",
  position: "absolute",
  right: '54px',
  top: $(ele).offset().top + 20 + "px"
});
```

The Popup Div:

```
<div id="inboxMenu" class="inboxMenu">
    <div class="inboxMenuHeader">Your Inbox</div>
    <div id="test" class="inboxPlaceHolder"></div>
</div>
```

Screenshot

[image: Align Div with Table Cell]

Comment: Try and avoid setting CSS with jQuery when not necessary. Toggle a class instead.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I did but had some issues with events on mouseover - I could try this again...

Comment: BTW - if you make a fiddle, it'll be a lot easier to solve.

Comment: Did you test `left:'0'` instead of `right: '54px'`, or make a fiddle,

Comment: @securedeveloper Yes, I set it to 'left:0' and that placed it on the left side of the screen. As for Fiddle, I need to create a "dumbed" down version that causes the issue.

Comment: Then use `em` unit instead of `px` because it adjust according to device pixel ratio,